# How to Enable Syntax Highlighting for Python in ATOM

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using Python 3.7, and our class has transitioned to ATOM Editor for our IDE. The Professor is running Ubuntu and his works, and a few people have had there's sporadically work but I'm unable to get any syntax highlighting or error pop-ups (Even if I make obvious errors)

Comment: Atom is a text editor, not an IDE. Could he be running some plugins that you are not? Syntax highlighting should be automatic anyway.

Comment: He gave us a set of Packages to utilize ATOM in an IDE format with Python, however, a lot of the windows users are not getting any form of Syntax Highlighting, those not running windows are having no troubles it seems. He also took some Windows Labs we have and installed ATOM and the packages and ran into the same issues.

Comment: Ah I see. I run it on macOS so I might not be much help to you.

Comment: You should ask your professor which packages he's using, rather than asking others to wild guess (which is also off-topic on Stack Overflow). Anyway, Atom ships with Python grammar by default, meaning that highlighting should work out of the box (if you are using standard Python file extensions). For advanced support, have a look at [ide-python](https://atom.io/packages/ide-python).

Comment: We are using ide-Python that's one of the packages we installed. The issue is still that my Professor was unable to get the highlighting and error notifications on the windows labs he installed Atom on to see if he could figure out how to fix the issue, and even with the same packages and options enabled only the non-windows machines in class are performing highlighting for syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable syntax highlighting you need to have the 'language-python' package from [here](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language%20python&commit=Search). Then make sure the file you are editing ends in '.py'. If these two steps have been followed the syntax highlighting should be in effect. Also load the 'Script' package from [here](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=script&commit=Search). This package lets you run python scripts from Atom.

Comment: language-python is one of the packages we have installed.

Comment: I have found the built-in 'language-python' package to be unreliable.  Instead, try installing 'magicpython' and _disable_ language-python. (If you don't disable the default, magicpython won't be able to take over).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I haven't encountered any differences yet but i'll change to magicpython.